# How to create an Adhoc Build in IOS 4.3

Tags: build, adhoc, provisioning-profile

I am working on an application with xcode 4.0, I want to create an addhoc build for that  application,how to do this. And i am downloading the provisioning profile but one yellow triangle shows with Valid signing identity is not found. Please anyone give me the steps for creating provisioning profile and build(.ipa file) also.